PowerShell, ImageMagick, GhostScript to extract each page of a PDF as a separate image
I'd like to take a PDF and extract each page as an image. I've been able to do this with ImageMagick and GhostScript, but the results are incredibly bad quality. I've tried many different output options without any luck. The script below should be fairly self-explanatory. It works, but the image quality is really disappointingly awful compared to opening the PDF.

Is there a way to use ImageMagick in such a way that the images output are good quality?
What about using other tools, but ideally programmatically, as processing lots of PDF's would be awkward if I have to do them one by one in a GUI.

# Extract each page from a PDF as a png using ImageMagick
# ImageMagick requires GhostScript for PDF manipulation so have to make sure that is installed
# Current install folder: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI
# Chocolatey package does not inclued the 'identify.exe' command

# Path to the PDF file
$pdfFilePath = "C:\0\MyFile.pdf"
# Output directory for images
$outputDirectory = "C:\0"
# Image type to output to (tried jpg, png, tiff etc)
$imageExtension = "jpg"

# Check if running as Admin
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Write-Host "Please run this script as an administrator."; exit }
# Check if Chocolatey is installed, if not, install it
if (!(Test-Path "$env:ProgramData\chocolatey")) { Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) }
# Check for magick.exe on path; if not installed, install ImageMagick
$imageMagickExePath = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-*" -Filter "magick.exe" -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
if (!(Get-Command "magick.exe" -ea silent) -and ($null -eq $imageMagickExePath)) { Write-Host "ImageMagick not found. Installing..."; choco install imagemagick -y }
if ($null -eq $imageMagickExePath) { Write-Host "Error: magick.exe not found at $imageMagickExePath"; exit }
Write-Host "magick.exe found at '$imageMagickExePath'"
# Check for gswin64.exe on path; if not installed, install GhostScript
$gsExePath = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\gs\gs*\bin" -Filter "gswin64.exe" -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
if (!(Get-Command "gswin64.exe" -ea silent) -and ($null -eq $gsExePath)) { Write-Host "GhostScript not found. Installing..."; choco install ghostscript -y }
if ($null -eq $gsExePath) { Write-Host "Error: gswin64.exe not found, this is required by ImageMagick for PDF manipulation"; exit }
Write-Host "gswin64.exe found at '$gsExePath'"
# Add Ghostscript directory to the PATH temporarily so that ImageMagick can use it
$env:Path += ";$($gsExePath | Split-Path -Parent)"

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path $outputDirectory)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outputDirectory | Out-Null }

# Convert each page of the PDF to PNG
$imageNamePrefix = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($pdfFilePath)
$imageNamePrefix = $imageNamePrefix -replace '\s+', '_'

# Use ImageMagick's identify command to get the total number of pages in the PDF
$numberOfPages = (identify "$pdfFilePath" 2>$null | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
Write-Host "'$pdfFilePath' has $numberOfPages pages"
# Use ImageMagick's convert command to convert PDF
Start-Process $imageMagickExePath -ArgumentList "convert `"$pdfFilePath`" -density 600 -quality 100 -antialias -resize 300% `"$outputDirectory\$imageNamePrefix-%d.$imageExtension`"" -NoNewWindow -Wait

# Determine the maximum number of digits to normalise all page numbers to that length
$maxDigits = $numberOfPages.ToString().Length

# Normalize page numbers
for ($i = 0; $i -le $numberOfPages; $i++) {
    $pageNumber = "{0:D$maxDigits}" -f $i
    $oldFileName = Join-Path $outputDirectory "$imageNamePrefix-$i.$imageExtension"
    $newFileName = Join-Path $outputDirectory "$imageNamePrefix-$pageNumber.$imageExtension"
    if ((Test-Path $oldFileName) -and !(Test-Path $newFileName)) { Rename-Item -Path $oldFileName -NewName $newFileName }
}

# Remove the Ghostscript directory from the PATH
$env:Path = $env:Path -replace [regex]::Escape(";"+($gsExePath | Split-Path -Parent))

# command-line tools for manipulating PDFs:
# https://libgen.rs/search.php?req=pdf+hacks&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=defs
# pdftk (PDF Toolkit): pdftk is a command-line tool for manipulating PDF files. It can merge, split, rotate, watermark, and decrypt PDF files.
# QPDF: QPDF is another command-line tool for structural, content-preserving transformation of PDF files. It's particularly useful for linearizing PDFs, decrypting, and compressing them.
# Poppler Utilities (pdftohtml, pdftotext, pdfimages): Poppler is a PDF rendering library and its utilities provide command-line tools for converting PDFs to various formats such as HTML, text, and images. pdftohtml converts PDF to HTML, pdftotext converts PDF to plain text, and pdfimages extracts images from PDFs.
# Ghostscript: Ghostscript is a suite of software based on an interpreter for Adobe Systems' PostScript and Portable Document Format (PDF) page description languages. It can be used for a wide variety of tasks including converting PDFs to various formats, merging PDFs, and more.
# MuPDF: MuPDF is a lightweight PDF, XPS, and E-book viewer. It also includes command-line tools for extracting text and images from PDFs.
# PDFMiner: PDFMiner is a tool for extracting information from PDF documents. It includes a command-line tool for extracting text, images, and other content from PDFs.


Try using a Windows Virtual Printer, https://microsale.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044843553-Creating-a-virtual-printer-used-for-emailing-reports-and-viewing-reports-onscreen, which should print a whole PDF as images at a time.

Simplest method presuming you want 300 DPI PNG is use a "drop on me".CMD file or put a link in your "SendTo" folder. Either way gives an instant export of one file to images that can be very easily adapted for a folder of files.
Using 2024 64 bit version of Poppler PDFtoPPM binaries available from https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows
"path to\pdftoppm.exe" -png -r 300 -aa yes -progress "%~1" "%~dpn1"


So this 12 page PDF will export to same work folder.
For more complex usage, then extend the CMD file to run in current work directory with multiple files and or sub folders.

A similar command for GhostScript could be like
"path to\bin\gswin64c" -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -o"%~dpn1-%%04d.png" -f "%~1"

As per @KenS comment simplified to 000# digits using %%04d

Differences in output can be adjusted by altering additional switches, but as the 2 commands above stand GhostScript (on left below) produces more compact files.

Following the original post, in PowerShell, for a folder containing some PDFs, the following will loop through and extract the PNGs for each PDF. Replace the locations of pdftoppm.exe, gswin64c.exe, and the folder containing the PDFs as required. Note that for the gswin64c.exe numbering in CMD above, % on the console becomes %% inside a CMD script, so %%04d for CMD script, while %04d works in PowerShell):
$pdftoppm = "C:\Poppler\Library\bin\pdftoppm.exe"
$gswin64c = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin64c.exe"
$pdfs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\0\*.pdf"

foreach ($pdf in $pdfs) { 
    $pdfFullName = $pdf.FullName
    $pdfNameNoExt = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($pdf.Name)
    Start-Process $pdftoppm -ArgumentList "-png -r 300 -aa yes -progress `"$pdfFullName`" `"$pdfNameNoExt`"" -Wait
    Start-Process $gswin64c -ArgumentList "-sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -o`"$pdfNameNoExt-%04d.png`" -f `"$pdfFullName`"" -Wait
}



The numbered file format uses printf formatting, so if you want leading zeros and a specific length, try something like out%04d which will print 4 digits with leading zeros.
